# Command Line: get substring between 2 different delimiters

Tags: command-line, batch-file

how am I able to get a substring between two different delimiters which also is at a variable position within a given string.

For example:

```
String1 = "my first example {{my first substring}}"
String2 = "my great second example which has much more words included before {{my second substring}} and after the substring"
Substring1 = "my first substring"
Substring2 = "my second substring"
```

As you can see, the delimiter before the substring is "{{" and the one after is "}}".

All I have found regarding substring operations are strict position settings which do not help here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you only need one substring from each string. Here is a robust solution that handles any values except it cannot handle `!` in the value, and also `^` is stripped if `!` is in the value.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%S in (
  "my {{first substring}} example"
  "my {ignore {{second substring}} example"
  "my {{third {sub}string}} example"
  "poison character {{&|<>^^ "^&^|^<^>^^^^"}} example"
  "empty {{}} example"
  "my {first error}} example"
  "my {{second error} example"
  "my third error example{{"
  ""
  "Limitation: {{eclamation is stripped^^^!}}"
  "Limitation: {{caret ^^^^ is stripped if exclamation present^^^!}}"
) do (
  set "string=%%~S"
  echo(!string!
  call :get{{sub}} string sub && echo(!sub! || echo ERROR: substring not found
  echo(
)
exit /b

:get{{sub}}  inStrVar  subStrVar
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=!%~1!"
if not defined str exit /b 1
set "sub1=!str:*{{=!"
if not defined sub1 exit /b 1
if "!sub1!"=="!str!" exit /b 1
set "sub="
for %%N in (^"^

^") do for /f "delims=" %%A in ("x!sub1:}}=%%~N!") do if not defined sub set "sub=%%A"
set "sub=!sub:~1!"
if "!sub!"=="!sub1!" exit /b 1
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (""!sub!"") do endlocal & set "%~2=%%~A" & exit /b 0
```

-- OUTPUT --

```
my {{first substring}} example
first substring 

my {ignore {{second substring}} example
second substring 

my {{third {sub}string}} example
third {sub}string 

poison character {{&|<>^ "&|<>^"}} example
&|<>^ "&|<>^" 

empty {{}} example


my {first error}} example
ERROR: substring not found

my {{second error} example
ERROR: substring not found

my third error example{{
ERROR: substring not found


ERROR: substring not found

Limitation: {{eclamation is stripped!}}
eclamation is stripped 

Limitation: {{caret ^ is stripped if exclamation present!}}
caret  is stripped if exclamation present
```

There are two primary tricks to get the substring.

- `!str:*{{!` deletes everything through the first occurrence of `{{`.
- `for %%N in ...` creates a quoted newline in `%%N` so that the `!sub:{{=%%~N!` substitutes newline for all `}}`. The inner `for /f` then iterates each string separately and the `do` loop only keeps the first result. The `x` is prepended just in case the substring is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
@echo off
cls
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set String1=my first example {{my first substring}}
set String2=my great second example which has much more words included before {{my second substring}} and after the substring

call :extract %String1% 
echo %Substring%
call :extract %String2% 
echo %Substring%

endlocal
goto :EOF

:extract
for /f "delims={ tokens=2" %%x in ("%*") do (
    set Substring=%%x
)
for /f "delims=}" %%x in ("%Substring%") do (
    set Substring=%%x
)
exit /b
```

> I don't believe this gives the correct results. For example --- {{abc {123} xyz}} --- yields abc but I think the correct result is abc {123} xyz. – dbenham

That's right. To solve such issue we must have some printable char which is absent in source string (at least before finalizing delimiter).

For example, if such char is `@` the code may be

```sh
@echo off
cls
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set String1=my first example {{my first substring}}
set String2=my great second example which has much more words included before {{my second substring}} and after the substring
set String3=--- {{abc {123} xyz}} ---

call :extract %String1% 
echo %Substring%
call :extract %String2% 
echo %Substring%
call :extract %String3% 
echo %Substring%

endlocal
goto :EOF

:extract
set tempstr=%*
set tempstr=%tempstr:{{=@%
set tempstr=%tempstr:}}=@%
for /f "delims=@ tokens=2" %%x in ("%tempstr%") do (
    set Substring=%%x
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is more understandable ;-)

Comment: I don't believe this gives the correct results. For example `--- {{abc {123} xyz}} ---` yields `abc` but I think the correct result is `abc {123} xyz`.

Comment: @dbenham Another variant added.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:

```
set string="my great second example which has much more words included before {{my second substring}} and after the substring"
echo string: %string%
set "tmp=%string:{=" & set "tmp=%"
echo tmp:    %tmp%
for /f "delims=}" %%a in ("%tmp%") do set substr=%%a
echo substr: %substr%
```

Result:

```
string: "my great second example which has much more words included before {{my second substring}} and after the substring"
tmp:    "my great second example which has much more words included before "
substr: my second substring
```

It works but I do not quite understand how it is able to determine the substring of the tmp-string as it is not in its content.